# ExtJS 6 grid group by associated models

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, grouping, extjs6

## Context

A while ago I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19198773/1842261) to implement remote sorting and filtering. Using the format 'associatedModel.associatedModelField', I could easily resolve the expression in my server side code in order to query the database.

## Problem

While this does the job, I encountered another problem with **grouping** - which I have configured to be local - the **associated models**. If I group a column which displays an associated field, I cannot collapse or expand without errors. Doing the same thing for the root model of the grid doesn't throw any errors.

The problem can be reproduced in this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1f5q).

The error trace in the console log goes like this:

```
ext-all-debug.js:198133 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isModel' of undefined

getMetaGroup            @   ext-all-debug.js:198133
doCollapseExpand        @   ext-all-debug.js:198284
collapse                @   ext-all-debug.js:198207
onGroupClick            @   ext-all-debug.js:198380
fire                    @   ext-all-debug.js:20223
doFireEvent             @   ext-all-debug.js:21130
doFireEvent             @   ext-all-debug.js:64732
prototype.doFireEvent   @   ext-all-debug.js:54757
fireEventArgs           @   ext-all-debug.js:20983
fireEvent               @   ext-all-debug.js:20942
processSpecialEvent     @   ext-all-debug.js:188549
processItemEvent        @   ext-all-debug.js:188499
processUIEvent          @   ext-all-debug.js:168108
handleEvent             @   ext-all-debug.js:168061
fire                    @   ext-all-debug.js:20223
fire                    @   ext-all-debug.js:32463
publish                 @   ext-all-debug.js:32439
doDelegatedEvent        @   ext-all-debug.js:32489
onDelegatedEvent        @   ext-all-debug.js:32476
(anonymous function)    @   ext-all-debug.js:6662
```

In the code I have used the solution as provided above and I also applied for the the grouping feature. It isn't exactly clean code but it works as long as I respect the limits of the fix.

How should I tackle this problem? Based on the type of problem I suppose that means rewriting the whole grouping mechanism but I don't fancy that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question by accident. On the [official docs website](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping.html), this line tells you what to do:

> However, if you intend to group by a data field that is a complex data
>   type such as an Object or Array, it is necessary to define one or more
>   Ext.util.Grouper on the feature that it can then use to lookup
>   internal group information when grouping by different fields.

So you need to define an array in the 'groupers' config of the grouping feature:

```
 features: [{
            ftype: 'grouping',
            remoteRoot: 'Summary',
            groupHeaderTpl: '{name}',
            collapsible: true,
            groupers:  [{
                          property: 'Customer.Address',
                          groupFn: function (val) {
                             return val.data.Job ? val.data.Customer.Address: '';
                        }
               }]
            }]
```

If you group on on this column, the groupFn will be used to do the actual grouping.

Comment: I should also point out there are some bugs in previous editions of Ext regarding grouping and collapsing/expanding. According to Sencha, all of these should be resolved in Ext 6.2